# Modal dialog popup will raise when i click on button , the popup contain only Ok button.

Tags: selenium

Modal dialog popup will raise when i click on button , the popup contain only Ok button. I should close the popup by click on ok button .

Exception coming : Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present: First Name should not be blank

Comment: Use alert class and use accept method to close the dialog

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Alert alert = webDriver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```